# How to create a URI for downloading files without using a verb?

Tags: rest, api, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

I'm trying to develop a RESTful API using ASP.NET Core. According to RESTful guidelines I should use plural nouns for resource names and keep verbs out of my base URLs.

This looks like simple, but maybe not.

I currently have `firmwares` and the following URIs:

```
1.GET /firmwares - get list of firmwares (name, version, date)
2.GET /firmwares/{id} - get details of firmware with Id (name, version, date)    
3.POST /firmwares - create a new firmware in DB name, version, date) and upload a file
4.PATCH /firmwares/{id} - change name of firmware with Id
5.DELETE /firmwares/{id} - deletes record from DB and deletes a file
```

Now I need to add an endpoint to download a file. What URI eliminates verbs like `GET /firmware/{id}/download`?

These are some I thought of

```
  GET /firmware/{id}?action=download 
  GET /firmware/{file_name}
  GET /firmware/{id}/files
```

Could you (who have already implemented this) provide a URI that is more in keeping with REST?

Comment: what is the mime type of download?

Comment: @Nkosi application/octet-stream

Answer (score 1):

This

> **GET /firmware/{id}/files/*filename***

fits nicely within REST non-verb nomenclature. Also, [firmware](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/firmware.html) is both singular and plural so would make more sense than *firmwares* in your URI.

With only one file ever available, these options also avoid the verbs

> **/firmware/{id}/file** (file name doesn't really matter in URI)
>
> **/firmware/{id}/*filename*** (if you want to show the name)
>
> **/firmware/{id}/file/*filename*** (a mix of both)

Comment: Yeah, there is `firwares`, just typo. But firmware has only one file. Does it make any sense to write `/files/filename`? There always will be only one file but according this URL I expect that there are many files and I want to download one of them

Comment: See my updated answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: But what about plural ? "Also, firmware is both singular and plural so would make more sense than firmwares in your URI."  According to RESTful guidelines I should use plural nouns. So `/firmware/{id}/file` is not ok for me. `/firmware/{id}/file/filename ` doesn't make sense. `/firmware/{id}/filename` no, I don't want to show the name

Comment: If you follow the link in my post you will see that firmware **is** plural just like software (we don't say 'softwares' when talking), so it should be OK for you.

Comment: I talk about `file` but now about `firmwares`

Comment: I don't understand your comment. My basic thoughts are that `firmware` instead of `firmwares` is fine in the URI (because the plural of `firmware` is `firmware`, and that the paths I posted are RESTful and don't have verbs).

Comment: You suggest `/firmware/{id}/file` and I said  "But what about plural ?" Here **file** is not plural, isn't it!